# Difference between "won't" and "wouldnt"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, conditional-constructions

Here's an example :

> "My tastes are very singular, you **wouldn't** understand"

Now my question is keeping this sentence in my mind we can substitue "wouldn't" with "won't" here right? But what would that mean here?

Comment: if your question is answered/If you are satisfied with any answer given you can mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: Done that @AverageGatsby :D

Comment: Btw, have you noticed how i used "can" instead of "could" in "..you can mark it.."? Here, they are interchangeable as well but, here, it is actually more polite to say "can", since someone could interpret the conditional as if you would be questioning their ability to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: Yes they are, in this case, interchangeable

The accurate answer:

If we look upon the sentence from a theoretical viewpoint, the two sentences have slightly different connotations.

**"Would"** is the past tense of will (aux.v.). It is used as a conditionals and to express that something is **unlikely to happen**. (It is also used in polite requests, but in that case it is, as I explained [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222873/prefer-to-do-something-vs-would-prefer-to-do-something/222915#222915), a conditional).

**"Will not"** implies that there is as reason which ***hinders*** him/her from understanding your taste ***regardless*** of anything else. E.g.: "I will not tell you why therefor you wont understand it."

***But*** only a pedant would correct you or be disturbed by your  usage of "won't"

It is also worth noting that Google Ngram has around as many hits for "you would not" as for "you will not"

Comment: **Would** is not always the past form of **will*, here it is modal verb and here the conditional that you mentioned about is not obvious to me. Can you please be a little more elaborate?

Comment: Ok, so here a polite request has been made, like you said :)

Comment: @Man_From_India except for the very uncommon "Would that this happens." it is the past tense of will, ***espacially*** if it is used as an auxiliary verb. There is no conditional in the OP's example. As I mentioned in my answer, "it(would) is used as a conditional *and to express that something is **unlikely** to happen*"

Comment: @AverageGatsby I see, you just jotted down all the uses of **would**. I by mistake connected that conditional thing with the sentence of OP.

Comment: @ArdisEll well, real etiquette would suggest "***could*** you please be a little more elaborate?"

Comment: @AverageGatsby The use of **won't** is already standardized as far as I know and so there is nothing to frown about. There was a time when both **ain't** and **won't** were frowned about, though **won't** managed to emerge into a standard usage, **ain't** still is left behind. It is unknown (to me at least) why **ain't** could not make it as a standard form.

Comment: @Man_From_India you are just focusing on the contraction which is not the point. won't and wouldn't are to each other as ain't and wasn't. With the slight difference that ain't has more meanings/usage than just as a contraction of "Be not"

Comment: I commented that because of your claim "**But only a pedant would correct you or be disturbed by your usage of "won't"**"

Comment: @AverageGatsby thankyou your answer was very precise and helpful

Comment: @Man_From_India As written in my answer: won't may imply that there is a reason that will ***hinder*** the other person from understanding one's taste. ***Another example*** /interpretation of won't instead of wouldn't is that you hate whomever you are talking to and therefor ***will not*** explain your taste to him.

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing the two versions this way:

"[I'll tell you about it but] you won't understand. (simple future negative)

VS

[I'm not going to tell you because] you wouldn't understand (conditional future negative: i.e., wouldn't understand EVEN IF I were to tell you)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tendency of using contracted form, for example -

> **I will** -> *I'll*
>
> **We are** -> *We're*

The contracted form **won't** results from *woll not = will not*

There are many variations of *won't* - for example, *wonnot, woonnot, wo'nt* - but they now are either obsolete or restricted in some dialects. Some of these variants are recorded as early as the 15C

**won't** emerged in 17C as the standard form.

The short form of **will not** is **won't**

**Note -** *wont* and *won't* are not the same, they are different. Contraction of **would not** is **wouldn't**.

---

As for the replacement in your sentence, yes, you can do that without any changes being made in meaning. But there is a slight difference in tone. By using **would not** you make the sentence less direct.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put a punctuation mark here. "Won't" . I know it is a short form of will nit, but here my question is does replacing "wouldn't" with "won't" makes any difference in the meaning?

Comment: @ArdisEll At least in this case there is no change of meaning.

Comment: @ArdisEll well, atleast for pedants there is a change of meaning as I describe it in my answer.

Comment: @AverageGatsby Could you please point out the difference in meaning?